# How are the overridden method in the RecyclerView called?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

please find a code snippet  as below

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

@Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }
}
```

I am following an online tutorial [RecyclerView + CardView](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/recyclerview-cardview/part-2-adapter) in which the Adapter class extending `RecyclerView.Adapter` overrides a few methods like `onCreateViewHolder`.
    But I don't find where these methods are being called.

I have checked the Android docs and it says "The layout manager calls the adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` method. That method needs to construct a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and set the view it uses to display its contents."

but the `LinearLayoutManager` doesn't explicitly call the `onCreateViewHolder` method.

I would like to know how the overridden methods are called from the `Viewholder` class.

Comment: The overridden method is called from an inner class within the RecycleView class called `Adapter`. It returns `VH` which extends the `ViewHolder` class.

Answer (score 0):

createViewHolder() of ViewHolder inner class calls onCreateViewHolder() method to create a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder.